# "layout_alignParentBottom" does not work in the Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I was adding a Bottom Bar below the `ViewPager` (on the bottom of the screen) by using include but it does not work. I have tried all the methods by adding `LinearLayout/ RelativeLayout` to wrap the include tag, even `ViewPager`; or adding code like `layout_alignParentBottom=true`, `layout_gravity=bottom`.

Is there any method to put it at the bottom, or any problem in my code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eee"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/Bottom_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/id_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: place `include` below the `ViewPager` and give `weight` = 1 for `ViewPager`

Comment: `layout_alignParentBottom` will **never** work in a `LinearLayout`. But it will in a `RelativeLayout`. And `fill_parent` is **deprecated** since API Level **8**. Use `match_parent`, instead.

Comment: thanks. i replaced match_parent and i find the real problem is to add android:layout_gravity="bottom" to the RelativeLayout in Bottom_bar.xml file. thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

just try like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<include layout="@layout/Bottom_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/id_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1" >` These are only valid in a LinearLayout, since they refer to **weights**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#eee"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/id_viewpager"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<include layout="@layout/Bottom_bar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

LinearLayout draws every child by the order it is declared, so if *Bottom_bar* is declared before *id_viewpager*, it will draw above ViewPager. If you switch the order, you'll get what you want.

Comment: `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` These are only valid in a LinearLayout, since they refer to **weights**. `fill_parent` is **deprecated** since API Level **8**.